# Postgres Notify via trigger function that SELECTs the result of window function using new row?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, window-functions

I have a query that runs a select that operates on a range of rows to find and return the max, min, etc., e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    time,
    device_id,
    MAX(high) OVER(rows between 4 preceding and current row) as window_max
    FROM device_measurements
    WHERE device_id=1234;
```

I want to set this query up in a trigger function that returns the `MAX` over the newly inserted row, `NEW`, and the 4 previous rows.

So far, I can create a trigger that calls a function which calls `pg_notify` and uses `row_to_json(NEW)::text` to simply return the new row.

Can I have a listen/notify setup that effectively pushes the most recent result of that query / what's usually done in these cases? Just get the notification and re-run the query separately?

Comment: This sounds confusing. What are you trying to achieve eventually?

Comment: I want to have a live stream of data coming in, where a LISTENer is constantly notified of the new row. However, I don't just want that row, I want the MAX (and other aggregate/window functions) over the previous 'n' rows. Ideally without having to make a new query for each row, as the rows are constantly coming in.

Comment: Ok. How is "previous" defined in your case? Is there any way to identify the previous rows in SQL? This sounds like it would be easy to solve with procedural code outside the database.

Comment: Ordering the rows in ascending order, previous as in the most recent (latest) row at time t, then  t-1, t-2, etc. Yeah, I could, but I think it'd be cleaner and probably faster to have that managed by the DB.

Comment: There is no way in the database to tell the most recent row unless you have a timestamp column.

Comment: That's what the time column is -- timestamptz. My question is about how to get a trigger to 'send' realtime/live window data to a client that is listening for it.

Comment: A trigger can never send data to the client.